# Unespected empty result from second query

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that I run one after another.

The first query gives me Ids and names of Offices that have at least 1 listed Type (LiTy count > 0):

```
SELECT Off, OffId, COUNT(*) AS NumLiTy
FROM LiTyT
INNER JOIN TaOff USING(OffId)
WHERE Upd Is Null
OR (Upd < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10  HOUR))
AND (
    Def IS NULL
    OR Def NOT IN (2, 3))
GROUP BY OffId HAVING NumLiTy > 0
```

The second query gives me data for each listed Type.

```
SELECT Id, RG, Rif_Year, Rif_Sec,
    IF(Dep_Date='0000-00-00' OR Dep_Date IS NULL,'',Dep_Date) AS Dep_Date,
    Rif_Type, Rif_Obj, Rif_DCU, Rif_DC, 
(
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt1`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS P_RT,
(
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt2`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS At_Dep,
(
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt3`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS Disc,
(
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt4`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS Provv_C,
(
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt5`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS Provv_M
FROM LiTyT
WHERE OffId = '1'
AND
(
    LiTyT.Upd IS Null
    OR
    (LiTyT.Upd < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10  HOUR)))
AND
(
    LiTyT.Def IS NULL
    OR LiTyT.Def NOT IN (2, 3))
```

The issue is this:

First query gives me three offices with count > 0

```
Off      OffId   NumLiTy
Office_1    1      8
Office_2    2      2
Office_3    3      1
```

but, when I try to get data from first office (who has count = 8) I get no rows.

It's clear that the two queries are only apparently using same criteria, but I wasn't able to find the differences and fix them.

**EDIT**:
here is a schema to check the query but I tryed it on sqlfiddle and all seems to work.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dt1` (
`IdEv` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `IdLiTy` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cost_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rin_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Upd` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Notice` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=103 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `dt1` (`IdEv`, `IdLiTy`, `Type`, `Cost_Date`, `Rin_Date`, `Upd`, `Notice`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Rico', '2014-01-02', NULL, '2015-11-27 09:54:55', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, 1, 'Resist', '2014-01-17', NULL, '2015-11-27 09:54:55', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(3, 2, 'Rico', '2015-01-02', NULL, '2015-11-27 09:55:15', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(4, 2, 'Resist', NULL, NULL, '2015-11-27 09:55:15', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(5, 3, 'Rico', '1999-01-02', NULL, '2015-11-27 09:55:33', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(6, 3, 'Resist', '1999-01-07', NULL, '2015-11-27 09:55:33', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(7, 10, 'Rico', '2015-01-14', NULL, '2015-11-27 09:55:58', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(8, 10, 'Resist', NULL, NULL, '2015-11-27 09:55:58', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(9, 50, 'Rico', '2015-02-10', NULL, '2015-11-27 09:56:18', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(10, 50, 'Resist', '2015-02-12', NULL, '2015-11-27 09:56:18', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE `dt2` (
`IdEv` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `IdLiTy` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `Att_Type` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Part` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dep_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Upd` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `dt2` (`IdEv`, `IdLiTy`, `Att_Type`, `Number`, `Part`, `Dep_Date`, `Upd`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'MEMORY >', 2014006804, 'Rico', '2014-12-13', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(2, 1, 'DEP > DOC', 2014006803, 'Rico', '2014-12-13', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(3, 1, 'DEP > DOC', 2014006625, 'Rico', '2014-12-03', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(4, 1, 'DEP > DOC', 2014003219, 'Rico', '2014-05-30', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(5, 1, 'DEP > DOC', 2014000351, 'Resist', '2014-01-18', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(6, 1, 'ATT > COST', 2014000325, 'Resist', '2014-01-17', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(7, 1, 'DOM > FISS', 2014000001, 'Rico', '2014-01-02', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(8, 1, 'RICO', 2014000010, 'Rico', '2014-01-02', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(9, 2, 'DEP > DOC', 2015001574, 'Rico', '2015-04-08', '2015-11-27 09:55:16');

CREATE TABLE `dt3` (
`IdEv` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `IdLiTy` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Udi_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Udi_Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Es_Disc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Relat` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Group` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ru_Ord` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Upd` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `dt3` (`IdEv`, `IdLiTy`, `Udi_Date`, `Udi_Type`, `Es_Disc`, `Relat`, `Group`, `Ru_Ord`, `Upd`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2016-05-11', 'UDI PUB', '', 'MAGI', 'Meri', 0, '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(2, 1, '2014-12-17', 'CAM_CON', 'DISC_O', 'ABBR', 'Giu_Ca', 12, '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(3, 1, '2014-06-04', 'CAM_CON', 'DISC_O', 'ABBR', 'Giu_Ca', 8, '2015-11-27 09:54:55');

CREATE TABLE `dt4` (`IdEv` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `IdLiTy` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Relat` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pub_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Udi_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Udi_Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Outcome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Upd` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `dt4` (`IdEv`, `IdLiTy`, `Type`, `Number`, `Relat`, `Pub_Date`, `Udi_Date`, `Udi_Type`, `Outcome`, `Upd`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'ORD_CAUT', 201400396, 'ABBR', '2014-12-13', '2014-12-17', 'CC', 'ACC', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(2, 1, 'ORD_CAUT', 201400165, 'ABBR', '2014-12-13', '2014-06-04', 'CC', 'FISS', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(3, 1, 'ORD_CAUT', 201400023, 'ABBR', '2014-12-03', '2014-01-22', 'CC', 'FISS', '2015-11-27 09:54:55'),
(4, 2, 'SEN', 201500639, 'PASS', '2015-04-08', '2015-09-09', 'CC', 'IMPROCEDIBILE PER SOPRAVVENUTA CARENZA DI INTERESS', '2015-11-27 09:55:16'),
(5, 3, 'SEN', 200000894, 'SPEC', '1999-02-16', '2000-06-07', 'UP', 'IMPR', '2015-11-27 09:55:33'),
(6, 3, 'ORD_CAUT', 199900008, 'SPEC', '1999-01-07', '1999-01-13', 'CC', 'S_ACC', '2015-11-27 09:55:33');

CREATE TABLE `dt5` (
`IdEv` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `IdLiTy` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Number` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Relat` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pub_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Outcome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Upd` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `dt5` (`IdEv`,  `IdLiTy`, `Type`, `Number`,  `Relat`, `Pub_Date`, `Outcome`, `Upd`) VALUES
(1, 247, 'GP', 201500007, 'PASS', '2015-07-15', 'RES', '2015-11-27 09:57:44'),
(2, 258, 'GP', 201500008, 'PASS', '2015-07-15', 'ACC', '2015-11-27 09:58:12'),
(3, 287, 'DD', 201500018, 'MOLL', '2015-09-19', 'DE', '2015-11-27 09:59:07'),
(4, 395, 'DC', 201500143, 'MOLL', '2015-07-30', 'ACC', '2015-11-27 10:00:36'),
(5, 454, 'DC', 201500161, 'PASS', '2015-09-04', 'ACC', '2015-11-27 10:00:58'),
(6, 556, 'DP', 201500133, 'RIGG', '2015-06-10', 'ACCO', '2015-11-28 09:25:40'),
(7, 230, 'DC', 201500103, 'POLI', '2015-04-20', 'RES', '2015-11-28 09:29:01'),
(8, 230, 'DC', 201500090, 'POLI', '2015-04-02', 'ACC', '2015-11-28 09:29:01'),
(9, 771, 'DC', 201500259, 'POLI', '2015-10-14', 'RES', '2015-11-28 09:32:35');

CREATE TABLE `LiTyT` (
`Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Reg` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `OffId` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
 `RG` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Rif_Year` mediumint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Sub` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rif_Sec` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `Dep_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Rif_Type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Rif_Obj` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Rif_DCU` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rif_DC` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Def` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Def_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Upd` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1008 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `LiTyT` (`Id`,`Reg`,`OffId`, `RG`, `Rif_Year`, `Sub`, `Rif_Sec`, `Dep_Date`, `Rif_Type`, `Rif_Obj`, `Rif_DCU`, `Rif_DC`, `Def`, `Def_Date`, `Upd`) VALUES
(1, '1', 1, 1, 2014, 1, 1, '2014-01-02', 'ORD', 'xxxx', NULL, 'S', NULL, NULL, '2015-11-28 09:19:40'),
(2, '1', 1, 2, 2015, 2, 1, '2015-01-02', 'ORD', 'xxxx', NULL, 'N', 0, NULL, '2015-11-28 09:19:48'),
(3, '1', 1, 1, 1999, 1, 1, '1999-01-02', 'ORD', 'xxxx', NULL, 'S', 0, NULL, '2015-11-28 09:19:56'),
(4, '15', 27, 432, 2015, 0, 2, '2015-01-28', 'ORD', 'xxxx', 'S', 'S', 0, NULL, NULL);

CREATE TABLE `TaOff` (
  `OffId` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `RegId` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `Off` char(200) NOT NULL,
  `WId` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `TaOff` (`OffId`, `RegId`, `Off`, `WId`) VALUES
(1, 13, 'Office1', 'xxxx'),
(2, 17, 'Office2', 'xxxx'),
(3, 18, 'Office3', 'xxxx'),
(4, 15, 'Office4', 'xxxx'),
(5, 15, 'Office5', 'xxxx'),
(6, 12, 'Office6', 'xxxx'),
(7, 7, 'Office7', 'xxxx'),
(8, 3, 'Office8', 'xxxx');
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry 1--> As you see the two queries work on 8 tables ... I'll try to prepare an sql fiddle (but I'll need time); 2--> I expect 8 rows resulting from query on 1st office, 2 rows on 2nd office and 1 on third.

Comment: @Strawberry I edited the question and added a schema to run queries, but the test schema don't give errors.

Comment: Why are the tables and columns named in such an abstract way? It's very confusing and counterintuitive for the poor reader.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, I'm not a pro and I've much to learn

Comment: @Strawberry I've edited again: I changed some `Id` to `IdLiTy` in the 2nd query (sorry again)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the bug!

It was because of incorrect use of parenthesis in `WHERE` clause. So this is what I have now (**I deliberately over formatted**):

```
SELECT OffId, COUNT(*) AS NumLiTy
FROM LiTyT
WHERE Upd Is Null
    OR (
           (
           Upd < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10  HOUR)
           )
       AND (
           Def IS NULL
           OR (
              Def NOT IN (2, 3)
              )
           )
        )
GROUP BY OffId HAVING NumLiTy > 0
```

And:

```
SELECT Id, RG, Rif_Year, Rif_Sec,
    IF(Dep_Date='0000-00-00' OR Dep_Date IS NULL,'',Dep_Date) AS Dep_Date,
    Rif_Type, Rif_Obj, Rif_DCU, Rif_DC,
   (SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt1`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS P_RT,
   (SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt2`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS At_Dep,
   (SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt3`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS Disc,
   (SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt4`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS Provv_C,
   (SELECT Count(*)
    FROM `dt5`
    WHERE `IdLiTy` = LiTyT.Id) AS Provv_M
FROM LiTyT
WHERE OffId = '1'
    AND (
        Upd Is Null
        OR (
               (
               Upd < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10  HOUR)
               )
           AND (
               Def IS NULL
               OR (
                  Def NOT IN (2, 3)
                  )
               )
           )
         )
```